# Error connecting to oracle. Getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError for the method t2cGetCharSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, drivers

I am running a series of JUnits using Apache ANT using JDK 1.5.

All JUnits that use an Oracle JDBC driver give the UnsatisfiedLinkError shown below.

What native library is it looking for and how do I solve this? What should the PATH variable contain?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle/jdbc/driver/T2CConnection.t2cGetCharSet([CI[CI[CI[CII[SLoracle/jdbc/driver/GetCharSetError;)S
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.getCharSetIds(T2CConnection.java:2957)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:320)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:361)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:142)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:79)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:595)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:196)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:114)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:59)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.getNewPoolOrXAConnection(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:401)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionCacheImpl.setMinLimit(OracleConnectionCacheImpl.java:752)
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle JDBC driver is this?  Is it classes12.zip, or ojdbc14.jar, or another one altogether?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved!

It was actually an out-of-date ojdbc14.jar file causing this issue. All I did was update it and the problem is fixed now. The classes file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had this one, you should add classes12.jar or classes13.jar to your classpath (not sure about the name, it's been over a year, google these...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass -Djava.library.path=YOUR_ORACLE_HOME\bin to the JRE as a runtime parameter

So....

```
java [other java switches + runtime parameters] -Djava.library.path=YOUR_ORACLE_HOME\bin run-classname
```

Also, make sure the jar in the classpath is the same one as is in $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib... overwrite the Eclipse one with the Oracle one if necessary.

If this doesn't work it would help to know which version of Oracle you're running since this will affect whether you should be using classes12.jar or ojdbc14.jar

Answer (score 0):

"Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native. "

Means that it is looking for a DLL/so -- you probably are using THICK driver ? JDBC 2 driver ?

If yes, then you might want to add OCI.DLL, etc.

Comment: You tell the JRE where to find the DLL with -Djava.library.path

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem; resolved by changing the connection url from jdbc:oracle:oci:@//localhost:1521/service_name to jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/service_name