# JDBC Connection Exception with MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using windows server 2003 on VM vare on  which I have my database on MS SQL Server 2008 . Now when I used jdbc driver to connect my java code with database I am getting following exception. Kindly give some solution .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext(Native Method)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.GenerateClientContext(AuthenticationJNI.java:80)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2691)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at test.jdbcdemo.main(jdbcdemo.java:24)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/175055/738746

Comment: Which JDBC driver, and what connection URL are you using?

Comment: Can you show your connection string? Is SQL Server on the same machine as the Java code? Is it a named instance or a default instance? Are you sure the service is running? Are you using Windows auth or SQL auth? Are you sure you can ping the server correctly, that the right ports are open, etc.? Has this ever worked on this machine, or is this a new program and your first attempt to connect, or has something on the machine, the code, or SQL Server changed? Why does JDBC produce such meaningless and useless error messages?

Comment: I am using default instance and services are running and there is windows authentication.Port is default 1433. 

String dbtime;
String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String query = "Select *  FROM [eSchool].[dbo].[tblClass]";

try {

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=eSchool;integratedSecurity=true");
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = ((java.sql.Statement) stmt).executeQuery(query);

Comment: Is your VM on a domain?  I can reproduce this error on my home PC with Windows 7 Home Premium, and it's not on a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled `integratedSecurity`. This means that the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` needs to be on the library path of the jvm.

Most likely you do not have this library on your path, it is the wrong version or the wrong variant (x86 <> x64 <> IA64).

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I had this issue today. I don't know the first thing about Java but for me the fix was to copy Microsoft's JDBC driver to Java's ext folder.

sqljdbc41.jar needs to be copied to C:\[path to java installation]\Java\jre7\lib\ext\

Make sure you pick the right version (x86 or x64).

Also for Integrated Security I needed to make a reference to auth when starting my application.

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\[Path to Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQLServer]\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\auth\x86
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception when starting SpringBatch with an `JdbcBatchItemWriter` writing to MS SQL Server 2008.

Sqljdbc_auth.dll was on the library path. It turned out that I was running my SpringBatch application in Eclipse with JRE 1.6. I solved this by running it with JRE 1.7 (Eclipse JRE-Tab in Run-Configurations).